# File.mkdirs() creating a directory instead of a file

Tags: java, io

I am trying to serialize the following class:

```
public class Library extends ArrayList<Book> implements Serializable{

public Library(){
    check();
}
```

using the following method of that class:

```
void save() throws IOException {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File f = new File(path + "\\Documents\\CardCat\\library.ser");    

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (f));  
    oos.writeObject(this);
    oos.close();
}
```

However, rather than creating a file called `library.ser`, the program is creating a directory named `library.ser` with nothing in it. Why is this?

If its helpful, the save() method is initially called from this method (of the same class):

```
void checkFile() {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File f = new File(path + "\\Documents\\CardCat\\library.ser");    

    try {    
         if (f.exists()){
             load(f);
         }
         else if (!f.exists()){
             f.mkdirs();
             save();
         }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> File.mkdirs() creating a directory instead of a file

That's what it's supposed to do. Read the Javadoc. Nothing there about creating a file.

> f.mkdirs();

It is this line that creates the directory. It should be

```
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Comment: And also `f.createNewFile()`, to create the file that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pescis That's completely unnecessary. `new FileOutputStream()` will do that anyway.

Comment: You're right, the `FileNotFoundException` thrown confused me.

Comment: @ddmps In the case of a `FileOutputStream` that means the directory wasn't found. That's why you use `mkdirs()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the call to `f.mkdirs()` is your problem.  If the file doesn't already exist (which seems to be your case), the `f.mkdirs()` call will give you a directory called "library.ser" instead of a File, which is why your "save()" call isn't working - you can't serialize an object to a directory.

Comment: In other words, there is no such constraint. I don't really understand what this sentence has to do with it, or indeed what it really means.

Comment: It means that the OS is allowing him to create a directory called "library.ser".  When he calls "save()", he's ultimately trying to serialize to a directory, which is not possible.

Comment: It means that the constraint you mentioned is imaginary.