# Android and LibGDX : create XML file in local storage

Tags: android, file, libgdx

I want to check if in my `/assets/game/` directory there is a file `level.xml` and if it does not exist I want to create it. I use this code:

```
private static void LoadXML() {
      ProgressFileHandle = Gdx.files.local("game/level.xml");
      if (!ProgressFileHandle.exists()) {
         try {
            ProgressFileHandle.file().createNewFile();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      } else ProgressFileHandle.file().readString();
}
```

This code does not work, I get the error:

> java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

it works if I change
`Gdx.files.local("assets/game/level.xml");` 
to 
`Gdx.files.local("level.xml");` But I don't understand why.  How can I create this file in a subdirectory (`assets/game`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not clear if you're expecting to read from the standard `assets` folder that is packaged with your game.  You should be using `Gdx.files.internal()` to read from there in that case, though that `assets` folder is always going to be read-only on Android.

If you want to create another directory called `assets/` in the Libgdx "local storage" (which is equivalent to the Android [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)) you will need to create the directories before you can create a file in the new directory.  Just invoke [`.mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)  on the file handle to make sure all the required parent directories are created.

```
ProgressFileHandle.file().mkdirs();
ProgressFileHandle.file().createNewFile();
```

Comment: I was trying to save an external file with `Gdx.files.external("path/to/file")` and had to use `getParentFile()` before `mkdirs()` or the file would also be a directory.

In the OP's situation it would be:
`ProgressFileHandle.file().getParentFile().mkdirs();`
`ProgressFileHandle.file().createNewFile();`

Reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15212890/1136409).